# Qt print html to printer

Tags: qt, printing

I have some **HTML**，want to print to a printer. My Qt version is Qt5.5, and I wrote :

```
QFile x("E://a.html");
x.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
QTextStream in(&x);
QString html = in.readAll();
QTextDocument doc;

QPrinter p(QPrinter::HighResolution);
p.setResolution(QPrinter::HighResolution);
p.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::NativeFormat);
QPrintDialog printDialog(&p);
if (printDialog.exec() == QDialog::Accepted) {
    QSizeF paperSize;
    paperSize.setWidth(p.width());
    paperSize.setHeight(p.height());
    doc.setPageSize(paperSize);
    doc.setHtml(html);
    doc.print(&p);
}
```

I get the result. But the **HTML Content** is too tiny...
[image: HTML Content]

I want to print some different paper sizes,like A3, A4, A5 etc,I need the **HTML Content** auto adapt to the paper size.

Comment: Without `p.setResolution(QPrinter::HighResolution);` and `doc.setPageSize(paperSize);` it seems to give a normal size.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtprintsupport-index.html, where they recommend this code for scaling a printed widget:

```
QPainter painter;
painter.begin(&printer);
double xscale = printer.pageRect().width()/double(myWidget->width());
double yscale = printer.pageRect().height()/double(myWidget->height());
double scale = qMin(xscale, yscale);
painter.translate(printer.paperRect().x() + printer.pageRect().width()/2,
printer.paperRect().y() + printer.pageRect().height()/2);
painter.scale(scale, scale);
painter.translate(-width()/2, -height()/2);
myWidget->render(&painter);
```

Comment: QTextDocument isn't a widget though.